# Zend2 Skeleton: can't call /application/index/index

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Good morning,

I'm currently learning Zend 2 but already have experience in MVC. I installed the current zend2 skeleton application, which is reachable under http://learningzend.local/ on my local machine.

Now, I'm trying to understand Zends routing but I'cant reach /application/index/index. It returns 404.

Here is an excerpt from module.config.php. The only thing I changed was the type in the two latter routes, it was originally set to 'Literal' and 'Segment' without the path. The home route seems to work: when I change the action, the homepage disappears.

```
'routes' => array(
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
        // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
        // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
        // using the path /application/:controller/:action
        'application' => array(
            'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/application',
                'defaults' => array(

                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'Index',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),
            ),
            'may_terminate' => true,
            'child_routes' => array(
                'default' => array(
                    'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                            'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

And few lines below

```
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Application\Controller\Index' => 'Application\Controller\IndexController'
    ),
),
```

The controller is completely unchanged

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

I tried everything. Resetted the whole skeleton app to default but it did not change anything. Hope some Zend gurus can tell me whats wrong.

For completeness my VHOST entry

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName learningzend.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/learningzend.local/public/
    AccessFileName .htaccess
    <Directory /var/www/learningzend.local/public/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here comes....the solution!

The Apache2 setting AllowOverride in my VHOST conf does **not override** the same setting in apache2.conf, even if they point to different directories. So, go to 
    $ sudo joe /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
    Change the Setting at /var/www to
    AllowOverride All
    $ sudo service apache2 restart